# Does Objective-C have a method (or C function) returning object's format specifier for a given object?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to write my own method to make inspection of variables easier than I have it with NSLog - I want it to be a wrapper around the NSLog, so I need to somehow recognize a proper format specifier for any object passed to my method.

It would be nice to have a method like **format_specifier_for** that could do the following:

```
format_specifier_for(1) => %d
format_specifier_for(@1) => %@
and so on...
```

**UPDATE:**

Besides the accepted answer (it does answer the original question) there are two possible approaches to the problem:

1. From @Guillaume's answer: use LOG_EXPR method from http://vgable.com/blog/2010/08/19/the-most-useful-objective-c-code-ive-ever-written/.
2. Use *overloadable* attribute when defining methods as described here: [How to check if a variable is an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844469/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-an-object)

I think the ideal solution could borrow from both of these options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there cannot be such a function since you can always use several (in theory every one) format specifiers for the same data type. For example you can use `%@` to print the value of a `NSString` or `%p` to get the address in memory.

Comment: Thanks, you've confirmed my thoughts!

Comment: If there was a way to get the type of a C struct or POD type, you could write a macro or function that evaluated to a format specifier of your choosing. But afaik that's not possible either.

Answer (score 1):

Look at that: [The Most Useful Objective-C Code I've Ever Written](http://vgable.com/blog/2010/08/19/the-most-useful-objective-c-code-ive-ever-written/). The author uses the C `typeof` operator and the Objective-C `@encode` directive to do something like you want...